# Direct product of tensor powers is a coalgebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, coalgebras

$\newcommand{\ot}{\otimes}\newcommand{\op}{\oplus}$Exercise from **Kassel's Quantum Groups**:

> Show that the canonical isomorphisms $V^{\ot (n+m)}\cong V^{\ot n}\ot V^{\ot m}$ induce a coalgebra structure on $\hat TV=\prod_{n\geq 0}V^{\ot n}$.

[I've seen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofree_coalgebra) that it is possible to define coalgebra structure on a subspace of $\hat TV$. Is it possible to define a coalgebra structure on $\hat TV$?

Comment: I would personally say that this sounds like a mistake and the author forgot that you must restrict to a subspace. But I could be wrong.